# jquery-alert Use Enter key to close window

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery-confirm alert with an OK button. To close the alert I have to use the mouse, I would like to just be able to press Enter on the keyboard, is there a way to get the key press event and close the alert window?

```
$.alert({
  title: 'Error',
  content: errorMsg,
  useBootstrap: false
});
```

I have tried this but it didn't do anything.

```
$.alert({
  title: 'Error',
  boxWidth: '30%',
  content: errorMsg,
  draggable: true,
  useBootstrap: false,
  keys: ['enter'],
  action: function() {
    onclose;
  }
});
```

How do I link the enter key press to onclose?

Answer (score 0):

Define whole `$.alert...` with some variable and and using that variable close your alert box inside action function.

Example:

```js
var ErrorMessage = "Your Error Message";
var a = $.alert({
  content: ErrorMessage,
  buttons: {
    specialKey: {
      text: 'OK',
      keys: ['enter'],
      action: function() {
        a.close();
      }
    },

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.2/jquery-confirm.min.css">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.2/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you @4b0 . I can see the example works nicely but my code doesn't as focus is on the previous Modal that the alert is called from. How can I make the OK button in the alert box have the focus?